# Converting an Ellipse2D to Polygon

Tags: java, swing, geometry, shapes, ellipse

I have a Java swing application where I can draw hot spots. I am allowing user to draw Rectangle , Polygon and Circle.

For Circle I am using Ellipse2D

```
Ellipse2D.Double ellipseDouble = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,width,height);
        g.draw(ellipseDouble);
```

Above works fine and it does draw an ellipse/circle.

Now the problems when I want the region to be used in HTML Image map.

Html Image map doesn't support Ellipse so I was thinking to use polygon for Ellipse2D but really don't know how would I convert it.

Does anyone know how would I go about it converting an Ellipse2D to Polygon ponits?

Comment: HTML image map does support circles technically, as long as the shape is a pure circle but i'm guessing you already knew that.

Comment: Yes I knew but the problem an end user could draw an ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

Use `FlatteningPathIterator`.
See e.g. http://java-sl.com/tip_flatteningpathiterator_moving_shape.html where point moves following custom `Shape`.

You can get list of `Points` and create `Polygon`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  someone   will  find  this  one  useful:  this  is  pdfbox  ellipse or  circle (width=height)  draw  function inside rectangle,  it  make  ellipse  as  polygon  initially  to  draw.

Code  based  on  math  function  of  ellipse at  poin [0 , 0]:  x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1

```
private  PdfBoxPoligon draw_Ellipse_or_Circle_as_poligon_with_PDFBOX (
        PDPageContentStream content, float bottomLeftX, float bottomLeftY,
        float width, float height, boolean draw) throws IOException {
    PdfBoxPoligon result = new PdfBoxPoligon();


    float a = width/2;
    float b = height/2;

    int  points =    (int) (a*b/20);


    if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("points=" + points);
    }

    //top arc
    for (float x = -a; x < a; x = x + a / points) {
        result.x.add(bottomLeftX + a + x);
        float y = (float) Math.sqrt((1-(x*x)/(a*a))*(b*b));
        result.y.add(bottomLeftY+b+y);
    }

    //bottom arc
    for (float x = a; x >= -a; x = x - a / points) {
        result.x.add(bottomLeftX + a + x);
        float y = -(float) Math.sqrt((1-(x*x)/(a*a))*(b*b));
        result.y.add(bottomLeftY+b+y);
    }

    result.x.add(result.x.get(0));
    result.y.add(result.y.get(0));

    if (draw) {
        for (int i=1; i < result.x.size(); i++) {
            content.addLine(result.x.get(i-1), result.y.get(i-1), result.x.get(i), result.y.get(i));
        }
    }


    return result;
}
```